# PHP / MySQL: How to return info if record already exists (without update)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, insert, duplicates

I am using the below to insert a new row into a MySQL db. 
The query for this is stored in a PHP file (`ajax.php`) and the input values are passed to this via an Ajax call in jQuery.

Everything works as intended but I would like to return a message to the user if an email is already in the db. 
I know how to update a db row using **ON DUPLICATE KEY** but **can someone tell me how I can just check for this and echo something if it exists there already** (i.e. without updating it) ?
(email is a single primary key so I only need to check for this column.)

**My PHP:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$dob = $_POST["dob"]; 
$sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, dob) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $dob . "')"; 
if ($conn->query($sql)){ 
    echo 'DB Update successful'; 
}else{ 
    echo 'DB Update failed'; 
} 
$conn->close();
```

Comment: **Warning**: Your code is ***highly vulnerable*** to SQL injection attacks.  You should bind user input values to query parameters, not include them directly in the query.  Please start by reading this: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. I am new to this so I am writing this in steps. Currently I am just testing but will definitely look into this before putting it live.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need a simple `SELECT` call before inserting.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$email = $_POST["email"];
$dob = $_POST["dob"];
$sql = "SELECT email FROM Users WHERE email = " .$email;
$query = $conn->query($sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0){
    echo "There exists an user with this email";
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, dob) VALUES ('" . $email . "', '" . $dob . "')";
    if ($conn->query($sql)) {
        echo 'DB Update successful';
    }
    else {
        echo 'DB Update failed';
    };
}

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Just one question on this: What is the $row needed for here ? I only see one line referring to it.

Comment: actually its not needed, it just selects that user.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this: After the updates from RiggsFolly it turned out that his approach is actually better for what I need here so I accepted his answer but voted you up. Hope that's ok and thanks again for the help !

Comment: I did some more research on this after Gordon's comment on the above and eventually decided to stick with my initial feeling here so in the end I accepted this answer and voted Riggs' one up. Sorry for the back and forth and thanks again for the help !

Answer (score 0):

The simple way is just to count the occurances of entries in the table with the same email as you are trying to store. Counting rather than SELECTing means it is quicker and only a count is returned not a complete row that you have to then look at or count the rows in the result.

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$conn->set_charset("utf8");
if($conn->connect_error){
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$stmt = $Conn->prepare("Select Count(email) as cnt FROM Users WHERE email = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $_POST["email"]);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($cnt)
$stmt->close();

if ( $Cnt > 0 ) {
    // its already there so do whatever you want in this case
} else {

    $sql = "INSERT INTO Users (email, dob) VALUES (?,?)"; 
    $stmt = $Conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->bind_param('ss', $_POST["email"],$_POST["dob"]);
    if ($stmt->execute(){ 
        echo 'DB Update successful'; 
    }else{ 
        echo 'DB Update failed'; 
    } 
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Update: Thanks for your updates. This actually makes more sense for me so I will accept this answer. Thanks again for your help - it's the second time you helped me out the past days ! :)

Comment: Just to add here: I made two minor changes to the above when implementing this. Not sure if it's necessary but it looked more logical to me this way: 1) I changed the last part of the $countResult row to ...'" . $email . "'"); 2) I added a { after else.

Comment: Counting adds additional overhead (very minimal in this case because email is  a primary key, but a bad idea for similar problems).

Comment: @GordonLinoff: Thanks for that ! So for similar situations in general would you prefer Burak's approach ? I am new to this so I am trying to do it the right way from the start. :)

Comment: I did some more research on this after Gordon's comment and eventually decided to stick with my initial feeling here so in the end I accepted Burak's answer and voted this one up. Sorry for the back and forth and thanks again for the help !

Comment: @keewee279 . . . I would probably just do the insert and look to see if a unique key exception occurs.  There really isn't a need for two queries, and either approach introduces race conditions.